# Combinations of a list of strings with exclusions

Tags: python, combinations, python-itertools

I am working on coming up with an exhaustive list of component operating states for a system. I need one operating state for each component. I have developed unique indices for each operating state, of the form component#-OS#, so if component 1 has three operating states, they would be 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 and so on. I want to exclude duplicate operating states for each component, so that only one of each component is present. I am using itertools combinations but need to figure out how to incorporate the exclusions in an efficient way (my problem is much bigger than the sample problem below):

```
 from itertools import combinations
 indices=["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-2", "3-1", "3-2", "4-1", "4-2", "4-3", "5-1", "5-2", "5-3"]
 out=list(combinations(indices, 5))
```

As it is written now, out contains many duplicate operating states and is much longer than I would like. I could easily filter them out after the fact but this will be a very time consuming effort. When I take this to the full scale problem, there will be hundreds of millions of combinations so I need to figure out a way to efficiently restrict the output to include only a single operating state for each component. This may involve modifying the combinations function somehow but I'm not sure where to start.

Any ideas?

*EDIT*

To clarify, I'm hoping for output of the form:

[1-1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-1], [1-2, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-1]...[1-3, 2-2, 3-2, 4-3, 5-3]

Comment: Do you mean `list(itertools.product(["1-1", "1-2", "1-3"], ["2-1", "2-2"], ["3-1", "3-2"], ["4-1", "4-2", "4-3"],
                           ["5-1", "5-2", "5-3"]))`?

Comment: No. The list is not organized in that way. The operating states in my dataframe are spread out and not chronological for each component. I could figure out how to organize them that way perhaps if it would make things easier..

Comment: That's easy, I'm just asking if that's the output you want. I'm not really understanding your description.

Comment: I want lists of operating states with one unique OS for each component.. eg. [1-1, 2-1, 3-1, 4-1, 5-1], [1-1, 2-1, 3-1. 4-1, 5-2], etc..

Comment: Right, that sounds like the result of `product`. Can you confirm?

Comment: It looks like it could work, but I'm not sure the output format is how I would like it to be, it seems to multiply them together and that might make them difficult to separate out and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate the states for each component into a list of its own, and use `itertools.product`.

```
from itertools import groupby, product
statelist = ["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-2", "3-1", "3-2", "4-1", "4-2", "4-3", "5-1", "5-2", "5-3"]
statelist = (list(b) for a, b in groupby(statelist, lambda x: x.partition('-')[0]))
out = list(product(*statelist))
```

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. I will try it with my large case study :)

Comment: I'm actually finding some operating states are split up into two lists for the same component? Any idea why that might be happening?

Comment: @Kingle this assumes that they are grouped together in the original list, e.g. if you have `['1-1', '2-1', '1-3']`, you'll have problems. For that, add a `statelist.sort(key=lambda x: int(x.partition('-')[0]))` before with the line with the groupby on it -- it'll group all of the states for the same components together

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import product
>>> indices=["1-1", "1-2", "1-3", "2-1", "2-2", "3-1", "3-2", "4-1", "4-2", "4-3", "5-1", "5-2", "5-3"]
>>> d=defaultdict(list)
>>> for e in indices:
...     d[e.split('-')[0]] += [e]
...
>>> out = list(product(*d.values()))
```

Comment: This also works, but seems slower than @MoxieBall solution